# Merging multiple data rows into one

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table like below

```
CREATE TABLE #T(Name varchar(10),Online BIT, Offline BIT,F_Id INT)

INSERT INTO #T
VALUES('A',1,0,0),('A',0,1,100),('A',1,0,200),('B',0,1,100),('B',1,0,140),  ('C',1,0,0)
```

What I want is generate unique rows using combination of Name and F_Id but except the case when F_Id is zero.

Basically the output I am after is

```
A 1 1 100  --> Merging ('A',1,0,0),('A',0,1,100)
A 1 0 200
B 0 1 100
B 1 0 140
C 1 0 0
```

Started with something like below

```
SELECT Name,MAX(CONVERT(INT,Online)),MAX(CONVERT(INT,Offline)),MAX(F_Id) F_Id
FROM #T
GROUP BY Name
```

Comment: what about the A|1|0|200 row?

Comment: And why `A 1 1 100`?

Comment: @scsimon: Sorry, missed it, updated now

Answer (score 0):

If i am not missing any thing,you are just missing a where clause and this keeps `A|1|0|200` row as well

```
SELECT Name,
MAX(CONVERT(INT,Online)),
MAX(CONVERT(INT,Offline)),
MAX(F_Id) F_Id
FROM #T
where f_id<>0
GROUP BY Name,F_Id
```

Comment: I need to get the row `A 1 1 100`

Answer (score 0):

You need to do group by name n fid to get unique  result  over that

```
SELECT Name,MAX(CONVERT(INT,Online)),MAX(CONVERT(INT,Offline)), F_Id
FROM #T where f_id<>0
GROUP BY Name,f_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You should ensure that only different pairs of Name and F_Id are selected.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE #T(Name varchar(10),Online BIT, Offline BIT,F_Id INT)
>
> INSERT INTO #T
> VALUES('A',1,0,0),('A',0,1,100),('A',1,0,200),('B',0,1,100),('B',1,0,140),('C',1,0,0)
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> 6 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> SELECT #T.Name, CONVERT(INT,#T.Online) OnLine, CONVERT(INT,#T.Offline) OffLine, #T.F_Id
> FROM   #T
> INNER JOIN (SELECT   Name, COUNT(*) AS Num
>             FROM     #T
>             GROUP BY Name) U
> ON     U.Name = #T.Name
> WHERE  #T.F_id <> 0
> OR     U.Num = 1;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> Name | OnLine | OffLine | F_Id
> :--- | -----: | ------: | ---:
> A    |      0 |       1 |  100
> A    |      1 |       0 |  200
> B    |      0 |       1 |  100
> B    |      1 |       0 |  140
> C    |      1 |       0 |    0
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=87954c18d754378720bd3808cf0b3221)*

Comment: I need the row `A 1 1 100`

Comment: All combinations of (Name, F_Id) with the rest of the fields? because there isn't a row with `A 1 1 100`

Comment: I have add one more row with value C and updated the expected result

Comment: But this new row has F_Id =0?

Comment: yes, i only need to escape zero when there is another row with something grater then zero

Comment: Its from these two rows `('A',1,0,0),('A',0,1,100)` by merging into one